# In refraction at an interface, is it possible for the transmission angle to be negative?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction

There are two possible cases of transmission shown below:

[image: 1]

Is case 2 possible for the transmission? In other words, can the angle $\theta_t$ be on the other side? Usually, in the problems that I solve, I see case 1, but is case 2 possible, and why?

Comment: Hi, please post the source of your second drawing -- or the source of the claim that such a refraction angle could occur.  That makes it easier for us to explain how the actual phenomenon happens (or can't happen).  As you hinted, the Snell equations don't allow Case2 because there's no $sin(\theta)$ for real numbers that could make that happen.

Answer (score 2):

For "normal" materials that you find in everyday life and labs, the refractive index $n$ is positive. These materials will *always* behave as in your Case 1.

However, it is possible to produce materials which have a nontrivial structure at scales shorter than the wavelength, in which case the light only sees an "effective" blurred-out continuum which can have properties that would otherwise be impossible. This class is generally known as [metamaterials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial), and indeed it is possible to use this trick to produce [metamaterials with a negative index of refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative-index_metamaterial), for which the generic behaviour under refraction will be as in your Case 2.